# Implications for measurement of an initially localized free particle's wavefunction spreading out to infinity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

So, I have been attempting to wrap my head around what happens to a free particle that is initially localized to one spot. It seems that due to their different frequencies, the particle's wavefunction will eventually spread out to infinity. What would happen to such a particle that went unmeasured for millions of years, simply spreading out forever, say a photon? Could an electron in some random galaxy randomly absorb it by some far off chance, and then finally collapse its wave function? It just seems odd. I know that if you aim an electron beam at a double slit, you will most likely detect it on the screen, you just can't predict where it goes. But, what about electrons that are never detected? What happens to them?

EDIT: Why a down vote? I'm not ignorant about QM or something. I know the math for a free particle. SE turns into, up to a constant, the heat equation, and you get spreading out. I'm wondering what the consequences are for measurement. I will change the title to reflect that I suppose.

Comment: The particle is never localized in a single point. That would require an infinite amount of energy. A photon doesn't have a system in which it is at rest, so that's bad example for what you want. Photons always have a momentum and they will propagate in the direction of that momentum, so you would, at best, bet a Gaussian beam. A charged massive particle will always encounter some electromagnetic fields and it's the fields that are going to determine the long term state and by "long term" I mean  seconds in a small vacuum chamber.

Comment: Ok, so the photon was a bad example. Probably should have picked an electron. So, still what happens if I have an electron travelling through space? What makes it randomly decide to take on a value? At what point does the electron 's wave function collapse? And please don't say when it interacts, because at any given time, I believe the electron's wave function overlaps that of pretty much every particle in the universe. It it just that it chooses a particle randomly to interact with depending on how much overlap there is between the wave functions? Just a guess. What makes it choose a photon?

Comment: Think of the electron as a state of the wave function of a quantum field that is everywhere. What we are measuring is "one electron has been observed at x,t". If you repeat the experiment, you get the Gaussian wave packet distribution for low energy electrons. Nothing ever collapses because the wave function of the field also describes the measurement device and its internal states. The Born rule (aka "collapse") is merely a handy short-cut for not having to think about that part of the wave function when we are calculating the final result.